# How to integrate Ninject into ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web applications?

Tags: ninject, asp.net-core-2.0

I have found out that Ninject has recently [introduced support for .NET Standard 2.0 / .NET Core 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/3.3.0).

However, I cannot find any extension to actually integrate it in the Web application (e.g similar to [Ninject.Web.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/))

Looking on the code from an old ASP.NET MVC solution, I realized that the whole mechanism is different as the classic one relied on `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod` and `WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute` which are no longer available in ASP.NET Core.

Also, the old `Ninject.Web.Common` assembly provided several useful classes used for initialization - Bootstrapper, OnePerRequestHttpModule, NinjectHttpModule:

```
public static void Start()
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
    Bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
}
```

**Question:** is there any example of how to integrate Ninject into an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web application?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797105/264697

Comment: Here's an example of how to integrate Ninject with ASP.NET Core: https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject/Startup.cs

Comment: @Steven - I have also find this example and tried to use it, but got stuck because it uses some types I could not find: `Scope` and `IReadOnlyKernel `. Last commit was done about 1 year ago, so it might not be compatible with the current stable version of Ninject (3.3.0) and/or ASP.NET Core (2.0).

Comment: You need to use [Ninject 4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/4.0.0-beta-0134) to work with those examples, or do some small changes to get it working with Ninject 3.3. Those examples use Ninject 4, since Ninject 3 is not compatible with .NET Standard.

Comment: @Steven - latest stable version (3.3.1) lists .NET Standard 2.0 as a dependency and can be installed in a .NET Core 2.0 project.

Comment: Ah, it can? I missed that.

Comment: @Steven - I have tested with both 4.0 and 3.3.1 and it seems to work (not sure if injected instance in controller is caused by Ninject or ASP.NET though, however kernel.Get<TInterface> works, so at least the ninject part is properly initialized. However, I would stick with 3.3.1, as 4.0 is beta and the referenced answer argues about the final version not coming any time soon.

Comment: Hi Alexei, try to understand how this integration model works. It's important to understand this. There's no magic. Dive into the code, set break points.

Comment: @Steven - yes, my test service is being created via the custom code (`ConfigureRequestScoping`), so it works. Should I provide an answer containing working examples for both versions? It is a little bit different for version 3.3.1 like you said and also a minor change is required to fix an issue for 4.0.

Comment: It's always good to get your question anwsered, and answering your own question will be highly appreciated by other developers who are googling for an answer.

Comment: Created a [git repo](https://github.com/JanivZ/NinjectDotnetCore) implementing @Alexei answer above, so the next guy can jut download a complete solution instead of coping from here... - works great!

Answer (score 21):

### Short answer:

check [this project](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject/Startup.cs). However, it relies on Ninject 4.0.0 which is still in beta version and it seems far from a final version ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261521/ninject-in-net-core/46521359#46521359)). For Ninject 3.3.x look below.

### Long answer:

Thanks to `@Steven` I managed to create a working solution of ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Ninject (both 3.3.x and 4.0). The code is mainly from [Missing-Core-DI-Extensions](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/SampleApplication.Ninject/Startup.cs) Git repo, so great thanks to [dotnetjunkie](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie).

The following must be performed regardless of referenced Ninject version:

1) Include [AspNetCoreExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/MissingDIExtensions/AspNetCoreExtensions.cs) and [AspNetCoreMvcExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/blob/master/src/MissingDIExtensions/AspNetCoreMvcExtensions.cs) in your project.

2) Create a very simple service to use for testing the DI: `TestService` that implements `ITestService`:

```cs
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public int Data { get; private set; }

    public TestService()
    {
        Data = 42;
    }
} 

public interface ITestService
{
    int Data { get; }
}
```

#### [Ninject 3.3.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/4.0.0-beta-0134)

Change `Startup.cs` as indicated below:

1) add these members

```cs
private readonly AsyncLocal<Scope> scopeProvider = new AsyncLocal<Scope>();
private IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

private object Resolve(Type type) => Kernel.Get(type);
private object RequestScope(IContext context) => scopeProvider.Value;
```

2) Add to `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` (at the end)

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

services.AddRequestScopingMiddleware(() => scopeProvider.Value = new Scope());
services.AddCustomControllerActivation(Resolve);
services.AddCustomViewComponentActivation(Resolve);
```

3) Add to `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` (at the beginning)

```cs
Kernel = RegisterApplicationComponents(app, loggerFactory);
```

4) Add the following method and inner class:

```cs
private IKernel RegisterApplicationComponents(
    IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // IKernelConfiguration config = new KernelConfiguration();
    Kernel = new StandardKernel();

    // Register application services
    foreach (var ctrlType in app.GetControllerTypes())
    {
        Kernel.Bind(ctrlType).ToSelf().InScope(RequestScope);
    }

    Kernel.Bind<ITestService>().To<TestService>().InScope(RequestScope);

    // Cross-wire required framework services
    Kernel.BindToMethod(app.GetRequestService<IViewBufferScope>);
    Kernel.Bind<ILoggerFactory>().ToConstant(loggerFactory);

    return Kernel;
}

private sealed class Scope : DisposableObject { }
```

5) Create `BindToMethod` extension method

```cs
public static class BindingHelpers
{
    public static void BindToMethod<T>(this IKernel config, Func<T> method) => 
        config.Bind<T>().ToMethod(c => method());
}
```

6) Test DI by injecting custom service into a controller, setting a breakpoint into test service constructor and checking the call stack. Besides providing an instance, the call stack should hit custom code to integrate Ninject (e.g. `ConfigureRequestScoping` method)

#### [Ninject 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/4.0.0-beta-0134)

`IKernel` has been deprecated in version 4, so IReadOnlyKernel and IKernelConfiguration classes should be used (although above code should work).

1) Use the new class (`IReadOnlyKernel`)

```cs
private readonly AsyncLocal<Scope> scopeProvider = new AsyncLocal<Scope>();
private IReadOnlyKernel Kernel { get; set; }

private object Resolve(Type type) => Kernel.Get(type);
private object RequestScope(IContext context) => scopeProvider.Value;
```

2) 3) are the same

4) The method is slightly different:

```cs
private IReadOnlyKernel RegisterApplicationComponents(
    IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    IKernelConfiguration config = new KernelConfiguration();

    // Register application services
    foreach (var ctrlType in app.GetControllerTypes())
    {
        config.Bind(ctrlType).ToSelf().InScope(RequestScope);
    }

    config.Bind<ITestService>().To<TestService>().InScope(RequestScope);

    // Cross-wire required framework services
    config.BindToMethod(app.GetRequestService<IViewBufferScope>);
    config.Bind<ILoggerFactory>().ToConstant(loggerFactory);

    return config.BuildReadonlyKernel();
}
```

5) The extension must use an `IKernelConfiguration`

```cs
public static class BindingHelpers
{
    public static void BindToMethod<T>(
        this IKernelConfiguration config, Func<T> method) =>
            config.Bind<T>().ToMethod(c => method());
}
```

Comment: Step 3) is missing the code that actually needs to be added to the `Configure(..)` method, which I assume to be `Kernel = RegisterApplicationComponents(app, loggerFactory);`

Comment: @zeroid - it was indeed missing. Fixed it. Thanks. I am glad that more  programmers are fond of Ninject and try to use in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Alexei:  There's a line in `AspNetCoreMvcExtensions` that doesn't compile:  `applicationTypeSelector =
                applicationTypeSelector ?? (type => !type.GetTypeInfo().Namespace.StartsWith("Microsoft"));`  Any thoughts?  It's trying to apply `??` to `Predicate<Type>` and a lambda expression.

Comment: @zimdanen - I checked in my project and it seems to work. I am using Target framewor = .NET Core 2.0. What is your target framework? Also, are you using Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @Alexei:  Same thing: .NET Core 2.0 in VS 2017.  That exact line compiles for you?

Comment: @zimdanen - yes. Which language version are you using? My version is C# latest major version (default). I think this means C# 7.0.

Comment: @Alexei:  Mine is also `C# latest major version (default)`.  Same build error if I manually set it to `C# 7.2`.

Comment: @zimdanen - I have no other suggestions other than posting a question here, on StackOverflow. Just make sure to include the whole function body.

Comment: Are these external files from a random project still needed? Or have they been combined with a Ninject library/package since this was posted?

Comment: I am also running into issues, parsing `RequestScope` into `config.Bind<ITestService>().To<TestService>().InScope(RequestScope);` tells me `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'func<icontext, object>'

Comment: @Alexei great feedback, do you know if the same code can be used for .NET Core 3? Or there is an easy way? Thanks

Comment: @VAAA - never got to check it against .net core 3 yet (still swamped in 2.2 projects).

Comment: @Alexei thanks a lot, last question. Whats the benefit of using ninject instead of the built in DI framework that comes with core?

Comment: @VAAA - it provides support for more complex contexts. I am using the built-in DI framework for some time and I recommend using it unless there is a strong reason to switch something else.

Comment: @VAAA - it provides support for more complex contexts. I am using the built-in DI framework for some time and I recommend using it unless there is a strong reason to switch something else.

Comment: Appreciate it a lot @Alexei

Comment: How to register Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity using this solution? I try to use userManager in my controllers but when I do       kernel.Bind<UserManager<AppUser>>().ToConstant(usrMgr).InRequestScope(); where usrMgr is parameter of Configure method I have an error while using userManager in Controller : ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'UserManager`1'.