# Use Inversion of Control to construct dependency with caller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ninject

Given the following ASP.NET Core controller :

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public MyController(IDependency dependency) { this.dependency = dependency; }
}

public interface IDependency;

public class DependencyImplementation : IDependency {
    public DependencyImplementation(Controller controller) { ... }
}
```

I want `MyController` to have a new instance of `DependencyImplementation` injected, constructed with the controller it's being passed to. Ideally using Ninject.

The non-IoC version would be:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public MyController() { this.dependency = new DependencyImplementation(this); }
}
```

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747913/1236044

Comment: Your code causes a Dependency cycle. Dependency cycles are bad and should typically be prevented. So please explain _why_ you need that `Controller` injected into the dependency. Preferably using some code.

Comment: I think that `Dependency Injection` book provides solution for such kind of situations, yet uses the `this` hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would cause circular dependency. Only idea I have is to introduce factory:

```
public interface IDependencyFactory
{
    IDependency Create(Controller controller);
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IDependency dependency;

    public MyController(IDependencyFactory dependencyFactory)
    {
        this.dependency = dependencyFactory.Create(this);
    }
}

var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<Controller>().To<MyController>();
kernel.Bind<IDependency>().To<DependencyImplementation>();
kernel.Bind<IDependencyFactory>().ToFactory();
var controller = kernel.Get<Controller>();
```

Or maybe rather reconsider whole design.

Comment: "Or maybe rather reconsider whole design." that's it :-)