# Microsoft DependencyInjection to Ninject DI

Tags: c#, ninject

I have to change Microsoft DI to Ninject have you got idea how use this in startup?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Test.QuartzServiceJobs
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

other code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Spi;

namespace Test.QuartzServiceJobs
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, JobFactory>();
            services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
            services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();

            services.AddSingleton<ImportMapSaveDataForKoreaJob>();

            services.AddSingleton(new JobSchedule(
                jobType: typeof(ImportMapSaveDataForKoreaJob),
                cronExpression: "0/10 * * * * ?")); //every 10 seconds
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and Ninject - from another project

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(
                        new SomeNinjectModule(),
                        );

IoC.Container = new IoCContainer(kernel);
```

module Ninject

```
public class SomeNinjectModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            this.Bind(x => x
                .FromAssembliesMatching("Test.*.dll", "*.exe")
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .BindAllInterfaces()
                .Configure(y => y.InTransientScope())
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693305/how-to-integrate-ninject-into-asp-net-core-2-0-web-applications), the ideal solution would be to use ninject version 4 but it is still in beta.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini thanks I added as duplicated