# Ninject in .NET Core how to configure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ninject

Following this question asked here: [Ninject in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261521/ninject-in-net-core)

I can't find anywhere an explanation of how to configure ninject in a `.NET Core` application.

I understand its done in the  `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

Did anyone successfully accomplished that?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747913/1236044

Answer (score 1):

I have never personally used Ninject, but the common way to use custom IoC containers in netcore is to change the return type of the ConfigureServices method from *void* to *IServiceProvider*. In case of Ninject it would look like this:

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // register your modules here

        return kernel;
    }
```

...I have just tried it and it works, because the StandardKernel of Ninject implements the IServiceProvider interface of netcore.

Comment: Looks like the right direction, still getting error, I will update when I get it to work