# PlatformNotSupportedException Ninject Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, ninject

I have an iOS app, developed with Xamarin.iOS, that is using Ninject 3.3.0 for IoC. I am able to bind interfaces and implementations without issue, but I get a `PlatformNotSupportedException` on resolving those bindings with `IResolutionRoot.Get<T>()`. I am launching to a simulator on a connected Macbook. I have created a test (blank) iOS app to demonstrate the issue. Here are the relevant lines:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
  ...

  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
  {
     ...

     var kernel = new StandardKernel();
     kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();

     var test = kernel.Get<IFoo>(); //exception thrown here

     return true;
  }
}
```

Here's the top of the stack trace (can provide more):

> "  at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor (System.String name,
>   System.Type returnType, System.…"

According to [this](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/How-Injection-Works) site, the kernel creates these DynamicMethod's for its bindings. Since Ninject [is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261521/ninject-in-net-core/46521359#46521359) by .Net Standard 2.0, why am I getting this exception from such a simple operation?

Comment: Did you try using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.Ninject/? I've been using that in my PCL and iOS/Android project and didn't have any problems.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one Rob is using in his article. His sample code actually includes both Ninject and Portable.Ninject libraries, but it doesn't appear to reference the former at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Portable.Ninject works, so use that instead if you're on iOS. The following is an explanation of how I got there and why regular Ninject doesn't work.

System.Reflection.Emit [is not supported](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#System.Reflection.Emit). Which likely means much of Ninject will not work for iOS.

These links were particularly misleading to me:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod/

Having now read about this limitation, it's obvious the generation mentioned in this article impedes Ninject from working, though it's not explicitly stated.

http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/

The writer of this article mentions the limitation, though it appears he got it working.

Comment: tl;dr: use Portable.Ninject

Comment: Agreed. I've updated my answer to make the solution more accessible.

Comment: You can't use Portable.Ninject with .net standard libraries so this is not a solution to the problem

Comment: @Merian It is, because this question pertains to Xamarin.iOS. In the question I linked to an answer that indicated .NET Standard support, so theoretically you should be able to use Portable for .NET Standard as long as iOS isn't one of your target platforms

Comment: You mean: You should be able to use Portable as long as iOS is one of your targets with a big warning the package may not be fully compatible with your project on the class library projects. And according to the last sentence in the question .Net Standard looks like it is used :).

Comment: @Merian I wanted to use it (hence the question), but to fix the exception I had to use Portable for iOS (hence the answer). So my other platforms use Ninject, but iOS uses Portable. I had to restructure things to get to that fix, but it does solve the problem. It sounds like your projects are structured differently. Hope this helps