# How to Replace Built in IoC with my own IoC?

Tags: asp.net-core

As we all know In asp.net **Startup** class there is a method **ConfigureServices** we can add custom Services. Services are made available through Dependency Injection.

> ASP.NET Core includes a simple built-in inversion of control (IoC)
>   container that supports constructor injection by default, but can be
>   easily replaced with your IoC container of choice. In addition to its
>   loose coupling benefit, DI makes services available throughout your
>   app

My Question is how to Replace Built in IoC with my Own IoC?

Please provide me an example if you have.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of different containers currently available for ASP.NET Core, including

- Autofac: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html
- StructureMap: http://andrewlock.net/getting-started-with-structuremap-in-asp-net-core/
- SimpleInjector: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html
- DryIoc (RC2 only atm): https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc

Exactly how you use them differs in each case, but essentially they all follow the same pattern:

- Register dependencies as usual using the built-in container
- Create an instance of your third-party Container
- Add any additional registrations to your third-party container
- Populate the new container with registrations from the built-in container
- Return an `IServiceProvider` from your third-party container

It might be worth taking note that there are a number of conversations happening around the way these libraries will integrate with the built in container going forward. The comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797105/6375486) provides a good summary of the conversation, or you can dive right into the discussions on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/pull/416#issuecomment-230789847) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/433).

Comment: "but essentially they all follow the same pattern". This is not the case for Simple Injector as described in the referenced integration page. Simple Injector runs side-by-side with the built-in container.