# Mocking multiple instances of interface: Setup of the last mock affects the others

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, moq, factory-pattern

Following my question about [conditional-dependency-resolver-on-run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57758285/6844481)

I built a `BooService` that has a injected array of `IFooService[]`, And a `FooFactory` method that return one of the foo services based on a given key on run time.

```
class BooService
{
    readonly IFooService[] _fooServices;

    BooService(IFooService[] services)
    {
        this._fooServices = services;
    }
    IFooService FooFactory(Guid id)
    {
        IFooService fooService = Array.Find(this._fooServices, 
                                     service => service.Id == id);
        return fooService;
    }
}

public class FooService1 : IFooService
{
    public int Id { get { return 1; }  
}
public class FooService2 : IFooService
{
    public int Id { get { return 2; }  
}
```

Everything works OK on run-time but my UnitTests fails:

```
AutoMock _mock = Autofac.Extras.Moq.AutoMock.GetLoose();
Mock<IFooService> fooService1 = _mock.Mock<IFooService>();
fooService1
    .Setup(x => x.Id)
    .Returns(1);

Mock<IFooService> fooService2 = _mock.Mock<IFooService>();
fooService2
    .Setup(x => x.Id)
    .Returns(2);

IFooService[] fooServices = new IFooService[] { fooService1.Object, fooService2.Object };

BooService booService = new BooService(fooServices);
booService.FooFactory(1); //Result in null
booService.FooFactory(2); //Result in "fooService2"
```

For the id of 1 the line code of `Array.Find(this._fooServices, ...);` result in `null`!

When I comment the creation of the second instance of the mocked interface the code of `booService.FooFactory(1);` result in `fooService1`. 
So I guessing the second `Setup` affects somehow on the first instance.

Any suggestion why when creating two mocked instance of the interface makes the `Array.Find(...)` **find only last created mocked instance**?

If it is a bug in `Moq`: any clean work around to unit test the find process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_mock.Mock<IFooService>()
```

Will return the same mocked instance for each call so the setup is actually being done on one instance. Last setup wins every time.

Here is the manual approach

```
IFooService fooService1 = Mock.Of<IFooService>(_ => _.Id == 1);
IFooService fooService2 = Mock.Of<IFooService>(_ => _.Id == 2);

IFooService[] fooServices = new IFooService[] { fooService1.Object, fooService2.Object };
```