# Dependency injection pattern for polymorphism in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am reading about DI pattern in ASP.NET. I know it can create a instance inside another class. For example, we have class HomeController need to have service instance like this:

```
class HomeController{
   private IService service;
   public HomeController(IService s){
     this.service = s;
   }
}
```

IService is implemented by WaterService class.

And we have code to register class which can be created instance, the instance can be type of transient, scope or singleton:

```
using DependencyInjectionSample.Interfaces;
using DependencyInjectionSample.Services;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService , WaterService>();
var app = builder.Build();
```

Then I realize, if IService is implemented by both class WaterService and ElectricService,  I have some situation, for example:

Call api to url  .../service/waterService: show infomation of waterService.

Call api to url  .../service/electricService: show inffomation of electricServic.

how can we register one of these class instance base on situation?

Comment: If there is at least one method in `IService` that is not implemented by either `WaterService` or `ElectricService`, then you would need to have separate services for both, because you will not want to break [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). That said, I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core) has what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional dependency resolver on run-time (.net Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758285/conditional-dependency-resolver-on-run-time-net-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problem but resolved by help of [The Answer was given by Shahar Shokrani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758285/conditional-dependency-resolver-on-run-time-net-core)

Let me know if still facing to implement DI.

Comment: well, most answer recommend using factory pattern, create a factory interface and inject factory class, then create concrete class base on situation.