# Using dependency injection for condition based instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have an interface and two classes

```
 public interface IReportGenerator
 {
    void Process(ActivityReport activityReport);
 }    

 class APReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
 {
    void Process(ActivityReport activityReport);
 }

 class ARReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
 {
    void Process(ActivityReport activityReport);
 }
```

In my controller, based on user input, I am instantiating the child classes like this

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
      private IReportGenerator reportGenerator;
      [HttpPost]
      public IActionResult Submit(ActivityReport activityReport)
      {
          switch(activityReport.Type)
          {
               case "AR":
                         reportGenerator = new ARReportGenerator();
                         break;
               case "AP":
                         reportGenerator = new APReportGenerator();
                         break;
          }
          reportGenerator.Process(activityReport);
          ...
      }
 }
```

Can someone please help me rewrite the code without the use of new?

In startup.cs, can I have something like this?

```
 services.AddScoped<IReportGenerator, APReportGenerator>();
 services.AddScoped<IReportGenerator, ARReportGenerator>();
```

And in controller?

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IReportGenerator reportGenerator;
    public AccounterController(IReportGenerator reportGenerator)
    {
        this.reportGenerator = reportGenerator;
    }
```

Sorry but I am stuck after this and dont know if this is correct or wrong.

Comment: Please refer to this question:
[Conditional Dependency Resolution Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758285/conditional-dependency-resolver-on-run-time-net-core) Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java doctrine applies in this case, being: when in doubt, use a factory:

```
public interface IReportGenerator
{
    string Prefix { get; }

    void Process();
}

public interface IReportGeneratorFactory
{
    IReportGenerator GetReportGenerator(string prefix);
}
```

You then let each report generator report which prefixes it can handle:

```
internal class APReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
{
    public string Prefix => "AP";

    public void Process(ActivityReport activityReport) { }
}
```

And create a factory that stores all registered generators with their prefix:

```
internal class ReportGeneratorFactory : IReportGeneratorFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IReportGenerator> _generators;

    public ReportFactory(IEnumerable<IReportGenerator> generators)
    {
        _generators = generators.ToDictionary(g => g.Prefix, g => g);
    }

    public IReportGenerator GetReportGenerator(string prefix)
    {
        return _generators[prefix];
    }
}
```

The trick here is to accept an `IEnumerable<IReportGenerator>`, which causes the Microsoft DI to inject all registered `IReportGenerator`s.

You register this as such:

```
services.AddScoped<IReportGenerator, APReportGenerator>();
services.AddScoped<IReportGenerator, ARReportGenerator>();

services.AddScoped<IReportGeneratorFactory, ReportGeneratorFactory>();
```

Then where you need a generator, you inject the factory instead, and based on the report type, obtain the relevant generator:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IReportGeneratorFactory _reportGeneratorFactory;

    public AccounterController(IReportGeneratorFactory reportGeneratorFactory)
    {
        _reportGeneratorFactory = reportGeneratorFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Submit(ActivityReport activityReport)
    {
        var generator = _reportGeneratorFactory.GetReportGenerator(activityReport.Type);

        generator.Process();
    }
}
```

This code still needs to handle two exceptional cases, namely multiple generators reporting the same prefix and a generator being requested whose prefix isn't known. The code shown will throw an exception in both cases.

Comment: "The Java doctrine", that's a good one. That's indeed what they do best in Java, factories building factories building factories. Although there are cases where the use of factory is the best solution, I experienced this to be often not the best solution. I, therefore, consider factories a code smell. Read [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/) to understand my reasoning.

Comment: @Steven nice writeup, interesting, thanks. The approach displayed in my answer does indeed not delay `IReportGenerator` instantiation, instead all of them get instantiated to feed into the factory. GuruStron's answer does that better. The statically-typed handler approach won't fly when the selector is a string instead of a typed message though (`ActivityReport.Type`).

Answer (score 4):

In some containers this can be achieved with [keyed/named](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) registrations but build-in one does not support this. So the usual approach is to use factory. Simple one using `Func` delegate can look something like the following:

```cs
services.AddScoped<APReportGenerator>();
services.AddScoped<ARReportGenerator>();

services.AddScoped<Func<string, IReportGenerator>>(sp => keyStr => keyStr switch
{
    "AR" => sp.GetRequiredService<ARReportGenerator>(),
    "AP" => sp.GetRequiredService<APReportGenerator>(),
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
});
```

And in controller:

```cs
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IReportGenerator reportGeneratorFactory;
    public AccounterController(Func<string, IReportGenerator> reportGeneratorFactory)
    {
        this.reportGeneratorFactory = reportGeneratorFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Submit(ActivityReport activityReport)
    {
         var generator = reportGeneratorFactory(activityReport.Type);
         // use generator 
    }
}
```

P.S.

Your approach will lead to `ARReportGenerator` always being used (because it was added last).