# Ninject and IServiceProvider/NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ninject

I've (My client) have a project which is being ported over to .net core, and thus the ninject dependency is being removed (as it doesn't support core yet).

I have some things in the project which call `Kernal.Get<T>` of things that aren't bound in Ninject, yet it still finds them.

Am I correct in saying it can look things up without knowing about them? And will I have to recreate this functionality myself for .netcore?

Comment: since version 3.3.0 Ninject supports .Net standard 2.0 and .Net core 2.0

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32797105/264697

Comment: There are like zero docs tho

Answer (score 1):

There's a fallback where if you request a a non-abstract class type - one that you can instanciate - ninject will create that as if you'd have written a `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()` (...`.InTransientScope()`, which is the default).

What it doesn't automagically do is create a mapping from an interface (or abstract type) to an instanciatable class. So `IFoo` => `Foo` requires a binding.
However, if you seem to experience such automagics it might be because the project employs [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions).